# add new module symfony version 1.011

Tags: php, symfony1

I can't add a new module .  Module - **dashboard**, application - **ulife**

These are the commands that I've tried

```
php symfony generate:module frontend dashboard

php symfony init-module ulife dashboard

symfony init-module ulife dashboard

symfony generate:module frontend dashboard

php generate:module ulife dashboard
```

Errors are

```
[pakeException]
Task "generate:module" is not defined.
```

Or

```
[Exception]
application "ulife" does not exist
```

ls -l  (of apps folder)

```
drwxrwxr-x 8 www-data ulifeweb 256 Oct  1  2009 frontend
```

Comment: What happens when you try these commands? do you get any errors or warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If :

- your application is **ulife**
- the new module name is **dashboard**

You should run :

```
php symfony init-module ulife dashboard
```

But according to errors you get:

- it seems that *ulife* application doesn't exist. Could you show us the output of `ls -l` in your `/apps` ?
- why did you try with `frontend` ?

**edit:**

Alright, so you only have a `frontend` application. What is *ulife* then ?

Try this to create your module :

```
php symfony init-module frontend dashboard
```

Comment: To be honest ulife is the site, not sure what frontend was. This is legacy code not sure why they named it frontend.

Comment: `frontend` is usually the name you give to the first application you create in a symfony project. Did you try the command ?

Answer (score 0):

Please following the doc of following link:

http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/book/1_2/en/04-The-Basics-of-Page-Creation

It will help you to create new module in existing pr